# spring cloud dataflow on kubernetes error on deploy

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, kubernetes-ingress, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am working on spring cloud dataflow stream app. I am able to run Spring cloud data flow server  with the skipper running in Cloud Foundry  . Now i am trying to run the same with the skipper running in kubernetes cluster and getting below error on deployment even though i am explicitly giving the username in the environment config in deployment.

> Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException:
>   Failure executing: GET at:
>   kubernetes_cluster_url:6443/api/v1/namespaces/pocdev/services?labelSelector=spring-app-id%3Dtest444-pocclient
>   . Service account may have been revoked. services is forbidden: User
>   "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in
>   the namespace "poc-dev".

**SKIPPER  YML for KUBERNETES DEPLOYMENT**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: skipper-server
      labels:
        app: skipper-server
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: skipper-server
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: skipper-server
          annotations:
            kubernetes.io/psp: nonroot
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: skipper-server
              image: <image_location>
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              ports:
                - containerPort: 7577
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: "4"
                  memory: 2Gi
                requests:
                  cpu: 25m
                  memory: 1Gi
              securityContext:
                runAsUser: 99        
              env:
                - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_MASTER_URL"
                  value: "<kubernetes_master_url>:6443"
                - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_USERNAME"
                  value: "<user>"
                - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_PASSWORD"
                  value: "<pwd>"
                - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_NAMESPACE"
                  value: "<namespace>"
                - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_TRUST_CERTS"
                  value: "true"
                - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_CREATE_LOAD_BALANCER"
                  value: "true"
```

**FULL STACKTRACE**

```
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: <kubernetes_cluster_url:6443/api/v1/namespaces/pocdev/services?labelSelector=spring-app-id%3Dtest444-pocclient . Service account may have been revoked. services is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "poc-dev".     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:476) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]      at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:413) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:381) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:328) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:598) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:63) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.kubernetes.KubernetesAppDeployer.status(KubernetesAppDeployer.java:196) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.kubernetes.KubernetesAppDeployer.deploy(KubernetesAppDeployer.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.skipper.server.deployer.DefaultReleaseManager.install(DefaultReleaseManager.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-skipper-server-core-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed when i removed below properties from the env  properties list and  skipper started using the default service instead of my user account

- name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_USERNAME"
                value: ""
              - name: "SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_KUBERNETES_ACCOUNTS_K8S_FABRIC8_PASSWORD"
                value: ""